# Blue Prism - Issue in Process/Object Element 'Not Connected'

Tags: amazon-ami, blueprism, spying

I have a process that uses a business object. It flows that it goes from the process to a object page to launch the website, then back to the process then links to another page in the same object as previous. When I run it I get an "AMI error occurred in WaitStart Stage 'Wait11' on page 'Sign-in' - Not Connected". I have a wait stage to check if the element exists

It seem like as I change between the object - process - object the element gets detached is there anyway to avoid this. If I step through the process I don't get this error.

Answer (score 2):

Call an "Attach" page at the beginning of each of your actions that performs the following steps:

1. Uses a Read stage to see if Blue Prism is "connected" (attached) to the application.
2. Uses a Decision stage to compare the output value of the previous action to True
3. If connected already, end.
4. If not connected already, use a Navigate stage to perform the attachment using the parameters you've set.

This best-practice functionality is covered on page 7 of the [Blue Prism Best Practice Build Overview](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2017-09/Blue%20Prism%20-%20Development%20Best%20Practice.pdf) document.